# Anchor tag not working on mobile bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently added an anchor tag to our homepage and it works fine on desktop but on mobile the link is not working.

I've searched for answers that do not involve adding additional Java or CSS amends (I do not have the ability to make those changes). Is there anything via the html that can ensure this works without me having to wait for one of our developers to investigate (lack of resource is killing me right now).

`<a class="btn btn-lg navbar-btn btn-dollar" href="#works">See how it works</a>`

I've added the corresponding id to a `<div id="works">` further down the page.

Comment: Show us enough code to replicate the issue. Read this: [MCVE]

Comment: Difficult to do so with the restriction on length...this is the page in question:

https://www.worldfirst.com/uk/

Comment: It may be difficult but it's also necessary. Once you fix your issue a link to your website will be of no benefit to future visitors of this question. Have a read of this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We don't need to see all of your code. Create a [MCVE]